# Is using an absolute path to load system DLLs with LoadLibrary() and GetModuleHandle() better to prevent DLL hijacking?

Tags: c++, windows, security, winapi, dll

In many cases to load some newer API one would use a construct as such:

```
(FARPROC&)pfnZwQueryVirtualMemory = ::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "ZwQueryVirtualMemory");
```

But then, considering a chance of *Dll hijacking*, is it better to specify a DLL's absolute path, as such. Or is it just an overkill?

```
WCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
buff[0] = 0;
if(::GetSystemDirectory(buff, MAX_PATH) &&
    ::PathAddBackslash(buff) &&
    SUCCEEDED(::StringCchCat(buff, MAX_PATH, L"ntdll.dll")))
{
    (FARPROC&)pfnZwQueryVirtualMemory = ::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(buff), "ZwQueryVirtualMemory");
}
else
{
    //Something went wrong
    pfnZwQueryVirtualMemory = NULL;
}
```

The problem with the latter method is that it doesn't always work (for instance with `Comctl32.dll`.)

Comment: This method will also fail if compatibility mode is enabled for your application by the user.My personal opinion - this too much trouble for the pretty little gain.

Comment: @Ari0nhh: Well, I disagree. Dll hijack of an application would be a pretty bad security issue. But, nonetheless, can you explain why would this fail if compatibility mode is enabled?

Comment: Well. If compatibility mode is enabled, Windows will supply specific versions of the system libraries, compatible with the selected mode. When you are loading system dll by its absolute path, you will always load current system version of the library. So application in WinXP compatibility mode will get Win7 dll and who knows what will happen. Dll hijack is of course an issue. But this is hardly a method to solve it. Better approach is to generate module signatures and check them on the load.

Comment: @Ari0nhh: You're too good to the compatibility mode. There's no "_specific versions of the system libraries_." They are all the same. In other words, Windows 10 doesn't have a separate set of DLLs for Win8, 7, Vista, XP, etc. What happens in compatibility mode is the OS simply lies to your process about its version via `RtlGetVersion` API, using a _shim_. There may be some other small nuances, but that is basically it. [Here's a short snippet](https://superuser.com/a/663050/516307).

Comment: You have a good idea about digital signature checking, way more complicated than what I showed, but good. There's one problem with it though -- you won't know which file/DLL will be loaded upfront, so that you can check its signature, before you call `LoadLibrary`/`GetModuleHandle` without specifying its absolute path, will you?

Comment: If the system has been hacked, then you can't really expect your app to be immune. Stop worrying about it. It's not your problem.

Comment: Have a look at "[Prevent DLL Hijacking Burn with Clean Room](http://wixtoolset.org/development/wips/5184-burn-clean-room/)". More info in [release notes of WiX 3.10.2](https://www.firegiant.com/blog/2016/1/20/wix-v3.10.2-released/).

Comment: simply link with *ntdll[p].lib` - absolute exactly as you link to *kernel32.llib*

Comment: `RtlGetVersion` as ntdll not lies and return to as exactly windows version. this is `GetVersion[Ex]` from kernel32.dll is can lies, dependent of manifest. and of course exist only one version of base system dlls like ntdll, kernel32, kernelbase, user32, gdi32.. (of course comctl32 another story)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The problem is avoiding your application causing the pwnage. If your application is in the downloads folder along with a planted evil version.dll (some browsers will/would download .dlls there without prompts) then you will be the one loading the evil code!

Comment: @Anders So what? I really don't see that as the responsibility of every third party app.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I agree but it is where we are until Microsoft lets you add something to the manifest to stop this. See the EVIL entries @ https://skanthak.homepage.t-online.de/advisories.html for example, software is getting called out for this constantly now.

Comment: This rather involves the attack being on the other side of the airtight hatchway. If the computer you're running on is already compromised it probably has a kernel exploit in place, in which case it can load whatever it wants to into your address space. In other words it's already too late at the point you're trying to protect your application.

Comment: @Mgetz no it does not, the problem is a evil .dll waiting for something to load it but until that happens the system has not been compromised. Ideally you don't want your application being responsible for loading something evil.

Comment: @Anders except evil.dll has to get on the system somehow in the first place. To do that it needs an existing compromise or trojan, evil dlls don't just appear. If your application installer is compromised then you're already in deep trouble.

Comment: @Mgetz See http://www.dhanjani.com/blog/2008/05/safari-carpet-b.html for example. Users will also just download random things to their download directory.

Comment: @Anders this is why you don't run from the downloads directory, you install to the protected `Program Files` directories

Comment: @Mgetz The OP did not specify if they are writing a installer so we might be back to the downloads folder again.

Comment: @Anders: I'm totally with you on this issue. Hate when vendors just shrug it off to someone else. The question is, Ok I get it, you blame some other software or the user for downloading a trojan, etc, but why not "secure" your code as well. Anyway, it's just a rhetoric at this point.

Comment: My application in question does not require an installer. It's a standalone executable that can run from any location. So yes, it can run from a download folder, from a temp folder or from anywhere else. Thus my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special for ntdll.dll and kernel32.dll because they are going to be loaded before you get the chance to do anything, they are also on the known-dlls list.

The dll hijacking issues often include auxiliary libraries. Take version.dll for example, it is no longer on the known-dlls list so explicitly linking to it is problematic, it needs to be loaded dynamically.

The best solution is a combination of 3 things:

1. Call [`SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh310515(v=vs.85).aspx) if it is available (Win8+ and updated Win7).
2. Call `LoadLibrary` with the full path (`GetSystemDirectory`) before calling `GetModuleHandle`.
3. Don't explicitly link to anything other than kernel32, user32, gdi32, shlwapi, shell32, ole32, comdlg32 and comctl32.

If `SetDefaultDllDirectories` is not available then it is really hard to protect yourself if you don't control the application directory because various Windows functions will delay-load dlls like shcore.dll without full paths (especially the shell APIs). `SetDllDirectory("")` helps against the current/working directory but there is no good application directory workaround for unpatched pre-Win8 systems, you just have to test with [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and manually load the problematic libraries early in WinMain.

The application directory is a problem because some users just put everything in the downloads folder and run it from there. This means you might end up with a malicious dll in your application directory.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case `SetDefaultDllDirectories` has to be pulled up dynamically using `GetModuleHandle` (unless you want your application to skip support for anything earlier than Windows 8.)

Comment: That is not a problem, linking directly to kernel32 and doing GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("KERNEL32"), "SetDefaultDllDirectories") in WinMain is perfectly OK.

Comment: This brings an interesting point. Obviously `kernel32.dll` will be loaded in your process at startup. But what if a malicious dll also named `kernel32.dll` is DLL-injected into the same process. What happens then when I call `GetModuleHandle` (with 2 `kernel32.dll` present)?

Comment: The real kernel32 will be the 2nd or 3rd module in the PEB module list (after .exe and ntdll) and will be found before the other fake dll if you are loading it without a path. Injected code could insert itself early in the list of course but if code can inject itself you have already lost. You should focus on not loading from a unsafe place, not defending against injections because the machine is pwned at that point.

Comment: OK. I see. Is there a rule somewhere that defines how `GetModuleHandle` picks which library to load first? The docs say, _"If lpModuleName does not include a path and there is more than one loaded module with the same base name and extension, you cannot predict which module handle will be returned."_ I'm guessing `SetDefaultDllDirectories` doesn't even affect it. As for _"not loading from a unsafe place"_, like I said, it's a standalone executable. It can run from anywhere the user chooses.

Comment: The load order is not documented but it is a linked list on all versions of NT. `SetDefaultDllDirectories` deals with not loading other libraries from a unsafe place. It does not deal with injections from `WriteProcessMemory`/`CreateRemoteThread` but that is a separate topic IMHO. Injected code can do whatever it wants to the module list but that is the least of your problems at that point.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. You're right. If DLL is injected its `DllMain` will be called automatically, at which point all bets are off. One last question. `SetDefaultDllDirectories` acts on a per-process level, correct? Not per-thread.

Comment: Correct, it is per-process and cannot be disabled after it has been called.

Comment: Nice! It didn't take Microsoft eight versions of Windows to realize a significance of such a function.